# Future tense "will be"

Tags: future

Which tense would be most appropriate in next sentence:

"Providing the correct software (to be) available, I should be able to help them with their problems"

I would go for "will be" but I am not too sure about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The first part of the sentence is not indicative, but an *irrealis* mood, meaning it is not real (because the software is not available; knowing software developers, it may never be).

This is a good place for the subjunctive. (Takes a step back, waiting for the Winter Bash to turn into a snowball fight.)

I might phrase the sentence as:

> "Providing the correct software *were* available, I should be able to help them with their problems."

Note that Microsoft Word gives me a green squiggle under "were" for my questionable use of the archaic, moribund, and generally unfashionable use of the subjunctive.

You could also say:

> "Providing the correct software *would become* available, I should be able to help them with their problems."

Microsoft Word does not object. Nor, I hope, those poised with snowballs on EL&U.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would use "will be" if the correct software wasn't available right now and "is" if it was.

Comment: But if you have to fill in the blank, what would you choose? Thanks

Comment: I would choose "is"

Comment: And would you have a grammatical explanation for that? Because i was told that present simple only refers to a timetable future

Comment: If it is used as a future tense